# I'm installing the K8s by the binary way. I configured the Scheduler, start it and found its status has some issues. How can I solve the problem?

Tags: kubernetes

[status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUSlJ.png)

It's config of the Scheduler.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uibpl.png)

I did the 2 steps .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQi4I.png)

Comment: is etcd and api server up and running?

Comment: Please post the code and error as text not an images.